# FFmpeg Creating mjpeg with boundary string

Tags: string, ffmpeg, jpeg, mjpeg, boundary

I am trying to play mjpeg real-time stream in HTML5 "img" tag generated by FFmpeg from my laptop webcam. When i open my website only the first jpeg displays. I think the cause of it is that my mjpeg stream is missing boundary string. Is it posible to stream mjpeg with boundary strings with FFmpeg

my cmd command: ffmpeg-f dshow -s 1280x720 -i video="HD WebCam" -f mjpeg -s 1280x720 -b 6000k pipe:1

Comment: ffmpeg command and log missing.

Comment: Tx. I Have updated my post with the command